# Hide the button when the screen scroll dwon and show when scroll up

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

i have a code like this:

```
<a href="/form" class="fixed-bottom" ><button type="submit" style="margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;display: block; name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">...</button></a>
```

this is fixed to under of mobile web page
i want hide button when page scroll down and show that when scroll up page

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use javascript events here in order to detect the scroll events on your page.

In the next example, there's an initial scroll position that is set to 0. You'll just have to compare this value to the current top distance of the page.

```
var scrollPos = 0;
// adding scroll event
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
  // detects new state and compares it with the new one
  if ((document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top > scrollPos) {
    // change here the style of your button

    console.log('going up');
  else {
    // change here the style of your button

    console.log('going down');
    // saves the new position for iteration.
    scrollPos = (document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top;
  }
});
```

[you have a working codepen here showing the example live](https://codepen.io/lehollandaisvolant/pen/ryrrGx)

Comment: Sorry can you make javascript by my id and html code?